# Is there a way to verify that an ajax request was made from a given domain?

Tags: ajax, node.js, security, http-headers

I'm open (and welcome) alternatives to what I'm about to ask - and am not interested in reinventing the wheel, so if there's a better approach I'd love to know about it.

My desire is to add an auth token to a browser based AJAX API call. The API is written in Node.js.

Given that browser based ajax calls are visible for all the world to see, I'm trying to come up with some scheme where exposing this key to a malicious user doesn't undermine the security.

As such, I want to combine the token with the domain on which the site is hosted to guarantee that the request is being made by an authorized user.

My concern is that there's no way to guarantee this.  I'm wondering if the incoming AJAX header can be spoofed somehow to make it look like the call is coming from abc.com when in fact it's being made from angry-north-korean-hackerz.net.

Comment: Is an `authorized user` a website owner of an authorised domain or an end user with an account on your domain? The security models required are very different depending on whether access tokens are client side (i.e. an end-user's cookie can be attached to the request) or generated on the server of an authorised domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reliably tell where an incoming ajax call is coming from.  Keep in mind when it comes from a browser, it's coming from the individual user's computer, not from any particular domain.  Plus, any non-browser client can also make the ajax call and send whatever headers it wants.

From another browser, as long as your server does not enable cross-site access, browsers will not allow other web sites to contact your ajax server as part of their same-origin protections, but this isn't enforced from non-browser clients.

If you only want your own code to make these ajax calls, then it takes some work to give you something that serves as a deterrent.  One way I've seen it done is that you put a regularly changing token in each of your web pages.  You send that token with each ajax call and your server validates if that's a legitimate token for this particular time period.  The tokens have to expire so a rogue client can't just harvest one token and use it forever.  This isn't foolproof as someone can try to regularly harvest new tokens with a scraper, but most will find that more trouble than its worth.